# How to convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a number that I received from a C program that came to me as a negative number:

```
-1771632774
```

It's supposed to be this number:

```
2523334522
```

I realized that this must be due to some conversion from an signed integer to an unsigned integer. Now that I have this negative number in Ruby, how can I convert it back to the unsigned version?

Answer (score 6):

Put the negative integer in an array. Call `pack` with an argument of `'L'` which represents "32-bit unsigned, native endian (uint32_t)". Call unpack with the same argument. Finally, get the number out of the array.

```
[-1771632774].pack('L').unpack('L').first
#=> 2523334522
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pack

Comment: You could do this slightly more hackily by just adding `2**32` to the number: `-1771632774 + (2**32) # => 2523334522`

Comment: Bitwise AND (`-1771632774 & 0xFFFF_FFFF`) is a non-hacky way.

Comment: Is the 'hacky' way bad if it gives the correct result?